# Switch between RDP sessions as fast as possible

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

Is there a way to change rdp sessions faster then clicking on minimize, then on the RDP symbl in the taskbar and at the end clicking on the desired connection?
Win + Tab does not work when I am in a RDP since it performs the shortcut on  the remote pc and not on mine.

Comment: `Control-left` and `control-right` works fine with Microsoft Remote Desktop on Mac. An other case where Macs run better the Microsoft programs.

Answer (score 3):

Remote desktop client is equipped with alternative keyboard shortcuts to supply common keyboard shortcuts inside your RDP session so you can keep original shortcuts for actions on your desktop. This way, you can still use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to rapidly switch between RDP sessions.

1. When your RDP session is maximized, press restore button on its blue connection bar (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>), so it will leave maximized mode.
2. Resize the RDP window to maximum size so it fills nearly entire screen. But some areas of your remote desktop will be off-screen so client window becomes scrollable. If you want to avoid the need of scrolling, you have two options, depending on your usage preference:

- *Keeping the same scale of content*: lower the resolution of the RDP session screen. (I typically prefer this one.)
- *Keeping the same screen resolution*: scale down the remote screen. Right-click title bar of RDP session window when sized as "restored" and in menu, check menu item
  **☑ Smart Sizing**.

3. Press

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between RDP sessions. **This is what you asked.**
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to switch between the tasks in RDP session.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to open Start menu in RDP session.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in RDP session

Given how much attention paid Remote Desktop Client developers to create alternate keyboard shortcuts, I would say this is the designed way of using multiple RDP sessions with ease.

▶ Source: MSDN article [Remote Desktop Services Shortcut Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa383500(v=vs.85).aspx)

- it also lists additional keyboard shortcuts
- that list from authoritative source is most likely complete so do not expect any other keyboard shortcuts doing some magic

**Tip:** if you find yourself *longer* working inside one remote session window, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to bring it full screen and use all standard keyboard shortcuts. Press it again to return it to standard restored size and return all standard keyboard shortcuts back to your Windows. All can be done without grabbing the mouse and clicking icons.

Answer (score 3):

I like MS's [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989), especially if you are dealing with a large number of remote desktops.  Everything can be done with a mouse, no keyboard shortcuts needed. You can create groups and subgroups to help manage large numbers of servers as well.  There are other 3rd party programs that do the same thing as well.

Comment: It's what I use.

Comment: Does it allow switching RDP sessions by keyboard as rapidly as if they are running non-maximized using standard Remote Desktop Client? Because while this RDCM has many additional functions, it is a question whether switching instead of Win+Tab (requested in the question) is anyhow accelerated by this tool. In the other words: does this answer the question? Maybe yes, but perhaps then you can extend the answer demonstrating this.

Comment: Updated URL for SysInternals rdcman: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman

Yes, it does allow fast switching, in 2 ways:
1) Using the same keyboard shortcut: ctrl-alt-break
2) Using a new shortcut to switch between RDP sessions even more quickly: ctrl-alt-left, and ctrl-alt-right.  
The hot keys are configurable.

Comment: I *hate* having to use the mouse to do anything.... If my fingers are on the keyboard, I want to be able to do everything without having to reach out to the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the normal 'Ctrl + Alt + Break' keyboard sequence, further customization is possible using AutoHotKey.

Related links:

1. [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) Open source Windows automation tool.
2. [RDP-Key](https://github.com/gildorwang/RDP-Key) Example use of AutoHotKey to customize RDP window switching.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).