# Minimize RDP session with an icon in the taskbar

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a way to have an icon in the taskbar that will minimize the RDP windows. We use RDP in our workplace, but have to switch from PC to RDP several times though a day, becuase of softphone and other things.

Are this even possible?

I've been looking for others asking the same question, and the closest answer I could find was this: [Switch between RDP sessions as fast as possible](https://superuser.com/questions/1253093/switch-between-rdp-sessions-as-fast-as-possible)

EDIT: I'm aware that you can use CTRL+ALT+BREAK, but isn't as user friendly.

Comment: You could use AutoHotKey to map the Ctrl+Alt+Break keyboard shortcut to something more user friendly?

Comment: But that would need to run on my PC, and if all my keystrokes get sent to the RDP session, how would that be activated? Please correct me if im wrong.